# Convert javascript variable into php and send it using session

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send article id using session, Source page contains many links to open one webpage but id is there in ID attribute of a href. like

```
<br/>
< a id="13" class="openpage" href="test.html">open test form< /a><br />
```

I have used javascript to pass the variable

```
$(".openpage").on('click', function() {
    var artid = $(this).attr("id");
    <?php $_SESSION['artid'] = "<script>document.write(artid)</script>"?>
    });
```

var artid is having the correct value before loading the new page and $_SESSION['artid'] is not getting the value of artid.

Answer (score 0):

> > You'll have to update your index file and the **test.html** becomes
> >     **test.php**
> >
> > **jQuery part** of the code takes the value of your ID attribute on the link
> >      Stores it in a cookie.
> >
> > In your **test.php** The value of the **COOKIE** is assigned to your SESSION and the COOKIE is cleared using the **in-built php set_cookie()**
> >     function to set the cookie with an empty value **(For security reasons)**;
>
> The **cookie** expires in **1 minute**. you can update it if you like.

-

> **//index.php file**

```
<a id="13" class="openpage" href="test.php" >open test form</a>

<!-- JS HERE ---> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

 function setCookie(key, value) {
            var expires = new Date();
            expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (60 * 1000));
            document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();

}

  $(".openpage").on('click', function() {
      var artid = $('.openpage').attr("id");
        setCookie('cookie_session', artid);
});

});
</script>
```

> **//test.php file**

```
 <?php
      if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie_session'])):
      $_SESSION['artid'] =  $_COOKIE['cookie_session'];
      setcookie("cookie_session", '');
      echo $_SESSION['artid'];
      endif;
   ?>
```

> Here's a screenshot of the COOKIE in the browser's **Dev tool >
>   Application > Cookies**

[image]

> As you can see the **COOKIE** is no more in your browser and the **SESSION**
>   now holds the data.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am not getting the value in test.php file while checking the $_POST['yourId'] in test.php file it is saying Undefined index: yourId

Comment: Ok. i'll go with another approach instead. Updating in a bit.

Comment: Answer updated with a new approach.